# Adding custom hyperlink to flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I have a flow wherein I am fetching a record of a custom object based on certain conditions. In the screen, I have a display text element wherein I want to display a hyperlink that opens up the record page.

Solution 1: I added the hyperlink directly as /{!getknowledgearticle.RecordType.Id}. It does redirect to the record page, but in salesforce classic. I tried making the URL same as the one that displays on the record page: /lightning/r/knowledge/{!getknowledgearticle.RecordType.Id} but this says "You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access"

Solution 2: I tried following https://jenwlee.com/2021/05/24/create-a-record-link-dynamically-in-flow/ this blog where the author makes a formula for the custom URl and then adds the formula to hyperlink.

LEFT({!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_340},FIND(“/services”, {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_340})) &{!getknowledgearticle.RecordType.Id}

This gives me a syntax error warning while trying to save the flow.

Can anyone suggest me what to correct in both the approaches or suggest a better one?

Answer (score 1):

We are using same formula as you except we are adding it to display text as link. The url is

```
LEFT({!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_340},FIND(“/services”, {!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_340}))/{!collaborationCase.Id}
```

[image]

Comment: I did try this, but it instead redirects me to the case record page I am accessing the flow from

Comment: you need to use your variable `{!getknowledgearticle.RecordType.Id}`

Comment: Yes @Damecek , I tried that only. I was not able to debug why but was able to work around with /lightning/r/knowledge/{!getknowledgearticle.RecordType.Id}/view ....adding "view" made the difference

Answer (score 0):

I had been encountering the same issue - by using:

```
LEFT({!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_540},FIND("/services", {!$Api.Enterprise_Server_URL_540}))
```

as a base URL formula it is successful.

I have a base URL formula - text (forT_BaseURL) using formula above. Then, in my chatter post, I have a Text Template (plain text) that posts to a group (tagging the appropriate user based on a previous 'get' earlier in the flow):

```
Attention @[{!Get_User_ID.Id}] there has been a late change to the Volunteer Shift record: {!forT_CustomDomain}{!$Record.Id}. See if this is correct and ensure that all paperwork has been submitted.
```

The end result is:

[image]